Excel document - How do I hide a formula/ value if there is no new data in a row?
enter image description here
I have created an excel document to calculate how many hours staff are still owed from working overtime and taking their hours. The calculations/ formulas are all correct, but I do not want to have any data in column I, unless there is data added to D OR H in the same row. How do I hide I from row 11 onwards? The formula I have in already, for example, I 11 is =sum(I10+D11-H11)
I hope someone can help. I am not a computer person so might need a little more explanation.
Thanks in advance.

What have you tried. I suspect a conditional formatting would work here

In I11 try =IF(OR(D11="",H11=""),"",SUM(I10,D11,-H11))

Thank you for your help. When I add =IF(OR(D11="",H11=""),"",SUM(I10,D11,-H11)) I get an answer of 0.260416667

A general answer to get you up and running...
Much of the decision-making in Excel is:
=IF(requirement-to-show-the-calculation; formula-to-do-the-calc; "")
In other words:
IF( this-is-true; do-this; in-other-cases-do-this )
note also:
=AND(this; that; more ) - true if all are true
=OR(one-thing; second-thing; third-thing) - true if a single one is true
=NOT(if-this-is-a-false-thing) - true
